# How to clean data where the variable name and property are in the same cell?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I need to clean data where the variable property and answer associated with a location are together in a single cell. The only thing consistent in my dataset is that they are separated by a colon (:).
I need to remap the data to the variable property becomes the column header and the data is mapped for each Location.

I've attached an example:

[image]

There can also be a bunch of other symbols that are irrelevant. I just need to extract the string before the colon and the string or integer after the colon and it is mapped correctly for each location.

How do I do this on R? What functions should I be using

Example data:

```
Example1    Sunny:"TRUE"    NearCoast:False Schools:{"13"} 2
Example2    NearCoast:False Schools:{"6"}   Sunny:"FALSE" 3
Example3    Schools:{"2"}   Sunny:"TRUE"    NearCoast:TRUE Transport:5
```

Also, would it be possible that I could add exceptions to this process. For example, if the cell is simply a number alone, it is ignored. Or, if the property name is a specific thing such as "transport", it ignores the cell too.

Comment: Possible solution would be to reshape-wide-to-long, then stringsplit on ":", then again reshape-long-to-wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example, as mentioned in comments, we can reshape wide-to-long, then string split on `:`, then again reshape long-to-wide.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = '
Example1    Sunny:"TRUE"    NearCoast:False Schools:{"13"} 2
Example2    NearCoast:False Schools:{"6"}   Sunny:"FALSE" 3
Example3    Schools:{"2"}   Sunny:"TRUE"    NearCoast:TRUE Transport:5',
                  header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(tidyverse)

gather(df1, key = "k", value = "v", -V1) %>% 
  separate(v, into = c("type", "value"), sep = ":") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  select(-k) %>% 
  spread(key = type, value = value)

#         V1 NearCoast Schools   Sunny Transport
# 1 Example1     False  {"13"}  "TRUE"      <NA>
# 2 Example2     False   {"6"} "FALSE"      <NA>
# 3 Example3      TRUE   {"2"}  "TRUE"         5
```

Answer (score 0):

In lack of a reproducible example, I can only provide guidelines. Assuming you can read in the data in a tabular fashion as shown in your 2nd image, you can do it with 4 "simple" steps with the packages dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.table(...)

df %>% gather(keypair, column, 2:4) %>%
  separate(keypair, into=c('key','value'), sep=':') %>%
  mutate(value=gsub('"{}', '', value)) %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

Go though each line, line by line, and try to understand what is happening before trying to run the next.